# Merging values in array of objects depending on matching values

Tags: php

I currently have an array in this format:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Size",
        "values": [
            "Small"
        ]
     },
     {
        "name": "Colour",
        "values": [
            "Red"
        ]
     },
     {
        "name": "Size",
        "values": [
            "Large"
        ]
     },
     {
         "name": "Colour",
         "values": [
              "Green"
          ]
      } 
]
```

I wish to loop through the array and as a result have its structure looking like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Size",
        "values": [
            "Small", "Large"
         ]
    },
    {
         "name": "Colour",
         "values": [
             "Red", "Green"
          ] 
     }
```

I wish for it to merge the "values" if the "names" match.

Comment: do you wants to check the values of both arrays and if they match and then to b e matches

Comment: @NipunTharuksha - For example, if there are two objects with the same "name" the "values" should be merged and the name kept.

Comment: did you tried with foreach and if inside it

Answer (score 1):

I've done some changes in your data to get the output and it might solve your problem.

```
<?php
$val = json_decode('[
{
    "name": "Size",
    "values": [
        "Small"
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Colour",
    "values": [
        "Red"
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Size",
    "values": [
        "Large"
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Colour",
    "values": [
        "Green"
    ]
}
]');
$output =[];
foreach($val as $v) {
    if(!isset($output[$v->name])) {
        $output[$v->name]["name"] = $v->name;
        $output[$v->name]["values"] = $v->values;
    } else {
        $output[$v->name]["values"] = array_merge($v->values,$output[$v->name]["values"]);
    }
}
$output = array_values($output);
print_r(json_encode($output));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply [**array_reduce()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) might be a solution for your purpose.

```
$result = array_values(array_reduce($data, function ($old, $new) {
    $old[$new->name] = $new;
    return $old;
}, []));
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/J1Igp)

Answer (score 0):

This my code, I first created this array in php and then used some foreach to solve the problem, this is the result

```
<?php
    //creating source vector
    $source=array();
    array_push($source,["name"=>"Size","values"=> ["Small"]]);
    array_push($source,["name"=>"Colour","values"=> ["Red"]]);
    array_push($source,["name"=>"Size","values"=> ["Large"]]);
    array_push($source,["name"=>"Colour","values"=> ["Green"]]);
    print_r($source);
    //initializind the result vector
    $result=array();
    array_push($result,["name"=>"Size", "values" => []]);
    array_push($result,["name"=>"Colour", "values" => []]);
    $i=0;

    //starting sorting
    foreach($source as $element){
        if($element['name']==="Size"){
            foreach($element["values"] as $subelement){
                array_push($result[0]["values"],$source[$i]["values"][0]);
            }
        }
        else{
            foreach($element["values"] as $subelement){
                array_push($result[1]["values"],$source[$i]["values"][0]);
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }


    //output
    print_r($source);
    print("<br><br>");
    print_r($result);
?>
```

And this the final output

```
    Array ( 
          [0] => Array ( 
                      [name] => Size 
                      [values] => Array ( 
                                [0] => Small
                                [1] => Large ) ) 
          [1] => Array ( 
                      [name] => Colour 
                      [values] => Array (
                                [0] => Red 
                                [1] => Green ) )  
)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($sourceArray as $element) {
    $newArray[$element->name]['name'] = $element->name;
    $newArray[$element->name]['values'][] = implode($element->values);
}
$newArray = array_values($newArray);
```